# How to override a method with generic type

Tags: java, generics

I need to override a generic method like below:

```
interface Converter{
    <S, T> T convert(S s);
}
```

Now I have Class A and Class B, I want to override above method by convert Class A object to Class B object. I did like below but all show error not implement the method. Is there a way I can specify the class A and Class B in the override method?

I tried below :

```
Class ConverterImpl implements Converter{
    @Override
    B convert(A a){
        //...
    }
}
```

I tried above, it has compile error says not implement convert method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is generify the interface.

```
interface Converter<T,R> {
   R convert(T toConvert);
}
```

and you implement it with

```
class AtoBConverter implements Converter<A,B> {
   B convert(A toConvert);
}
```

With your method declaration, each class would need to implement the generic version.

BTW it is usually good practice to use existing interfaces; in this case, this would be `Function<T,R>` with the method `R accept(T)`.